# Null data is inserted into database ever time i refresh the page without data

Tags: jsp

I have created a JSP page to insert data into the database. That is the only purpose it should serve however when I refresh the page it inserts null data into the database. I have got around it by giving if condition so as to display a message when no data is inserted. But it does  not look appropriate to display such message on refresh. Also I was wondering if I could use DAO to perform the task or a separate servlet. Please advice!

```
<form method="post">
Ticket Number:<input type="text" name=ticketNumber autocomplete="on">
<br>
Ticket type:<select name="type">
<option value="Old">Old</option>
<option value="New">New</option>
</select>

Ticket status:
<select name="status">

<option value="Transferred">Transferred</option>
<option value="Pending">Pending</option>
<option value="Strike 1">Strike 1</option>
<option value="Strike 2">Strike 2</option>
<option value="Strike 3">Strike 3</option>
<option value="Call back">Call back</option>

</select>


<br>

<input type="submit" value="submit"> 
<%
String ticketNumber= request.getParameter("ticketNumber");
System.out.println(""+ticketNumber);
String ticketType= request.getParameter("type");
System.out.println(""+ticketType);
String status= request.getParameter("status");
System.out.println(""+status);

if(ticketNumber != null || ticketType != null || status !=null)

{   
try
{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connectionconn=DriverManager.getConnection
("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","great123");
PreparedStatement ps=
conn.prepareStatement
("insert into ticketdb   (tnumber,ttype,tstatus)   values (?,?,?)");

ps.setString(1, ticketNumber);
ps.setString(2, ticketType);
ps.setString(3, status);
ps.executeUpdate();
}catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}

else
{
    out.print("You missed something!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have Java code in a JSP. A JSP is a view component. Its only responsibility is to generate HTML, using the JSP EL, the JSTL and other taglibs, and taking data from Java Beans stored in request attributes.

Accessing a database should be done in Java, from a DAO called from a controller (implemented as a servlet).

You're mixing two very different things here: 
1. displaying a form
2. handle a form submission creating data in database.

The first one should be handled by a GET request to the servlet. The `doGet()` method of the servlet should get the data to display the form, store it in a request attribute, and forward to a JSP displaying the form.

The form action should then be submitted, using POST, to a servlet (the same or another servlet). The `doPost()` method of this servlet should get the values from the parameters, validate them and, if valid, insert the data in the database, and redirect to another servlet, typically to display the data that has just been inserted, or to list the data in the table.

This is the basic of the MVC architecture. It separates the responsibilities cleanly, and avoid mistakes such as the one you did., among other benefits.

Comment: I downloaded couple of projects online to follow as a model and i found proper implementation of MVC only in the login page. So it raised a couple of questions. Is that bad programming? And which are model I should keep in mind before starting a project and lastly could you provide me some project links which i can refer to as a beginner, so that one day i can also get the pleasure of watching the unit test progress bar staying green until the end. Well I'm not supposed to say thanks as per comment section but really appreciate your time and effort.